# What is the difference between WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL, WS_EX_RTLREADING and WS_EX_RIGHT?

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, internationalization, right-to-left

I'm trying to localize my GUI app for some right-to-left languages and I'm struggling to understand what do `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL`, `WS_EX_RTLREADING` and `WS_EX_RIGHT` [window styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/extended-window-styles) do?

Here's an example. I set the following text to a `static` control:

```
LPCTSTR pStrTxt = L"בבקשה תקרא";
::SetWindowTextW(hStaticWnd, pStrTxt);
```

That control has these original styles:

```
Styles: 0x50020000 = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP | SS_LEFT
ExStyles: 0x400004 = WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY
```

Here's the results when I apply each of those style flags:

[image]

*PS. I don't speak Hebrew.*

Comment: [This useful article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140913090116/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688119.aspx) used to exist on MSDN. I can't find it anymore except on the Wayback Machine. I don't know why Microsoft does this.

Comment: @CodyGray: Thanks. That is because "everyone has to code UWP apps now." L) I'll review that article.

Comment: No, that's not the explanation. They've been rearranging MSDN for years, making it impossible to find things, even before there was a trendy replacement for Win32. Executive summary is `WS_EX_RIGHT` just makes the window generically "right-aligned". `WS_EX_RTLREADING` causes text to be displayed RTL in the window if the shell language/font supports that. `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` flips the window's coordinate system, so that the origin is at the right edge and the horizontal coordinates increase toward the left.

Comment: @CodyGray: yeah, I hear you bro. A "good" example is the [Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/) blog. With the new design pretty much *all* if its links are bad. If I was Raymond Chen, I'd be really pissed.

Comment: Oh no! They broke *and* uglified Raymond's blog?! I'm behind on my reading the past few months. :-(

Comment: @CodyGray: yeah, I felt the same thing. Listen, about the `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` and `WS_EX_RTLREADING` styles. They don't seem to do *what you described* in XP. (See my screenshot above.)

Comment: You probably need to install [RTL components](https://chronoplexsoftware.com/myfamilytree/kb/kb0005.htm) for Windows XP to have it work correctly.

Comment: @AlexCohn: Good find. Thanks. Is there a way to know that all that rigmarole is already installed so that I can safely display my RTL text, and if not, otherwise default to the English one?

Comment: Let me first ask you if Windows XP is so important to you? Because for Windows 7 and higher, this is built in.

Comment: @AlexCohn: It's not that, it's that my software will look stupid if I `secnetnes ni sdrow fo redro eht esrever`. My users don't have to pay for Microsoft's inability to code.

Comment: IMHO it is exactly that. The `WS_EX_RTL…` styles work as expected on updated systems. You can work around the situation on Windows XP with missing RTL components, but if this work will not show up for a single user, you probably can spend this effort on some other improvements for your product.

Comment: this is the new MSDN link to the article posted by @CodyGray https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/localizability/mirroring-in-win32

Comment: @Alex Cohn  Hello, does WS_EX_RTLREADING only work when system language supports RTL? I know MS doc says "shell language" but I struggle to grasp what exactly that is. Is there a way to force shell language for a win32 app to be Arabic on an English system? Thank you.